# how to configurate client-server openssl

Tags: openssl, client-server

everyone !
I need to make openssl client-server using s_server installed in openssl. 
How to configurate client-server with s_server ? As i understand, i need to make my own certificate.
Using Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Hi, this question seems very general to me and you might be better off searching for a tutorial

Comment: @Andy Can you share a link of tutorial ?

Comment: Found a couple on the first page of Google when searching for "openssl client-server using s_server".  This one has info about making a certificate - https://superhero.ninja/2015/07/22/create-a-simple-https-server-with-openssl-s_server/